# Triming a URL, Can Not remove a character

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am trying to trim a url with a formula after a set word within the url, I can do it apart from I can not remove the first character of the keyword, in this case it is "Company".

I am using this formula

```
=MID(A2,1,IFERROR(FIND(""Company"",A2),FIND(""company"",A2))+0)
```

From & To

[image: Url Image]

If I remove the +0 completely at  or change it to a 0 then I keep getting an error message and I can not work it out.

**Q) Can someone please explain why i can not remove the last character?**

Also if you can help can you please keep it as a formula as shown above, as I am limited in VBA

[image: Error message]

As Always thanks in advance

Comment: Try:  `=LEFT(A1,SEARCH("/company",A1)-1)`  or, in VBA, `Left(s, InStr(1, myString, "/company", vbTextCompare) - 1)`

Comment: Super, much better , Thanks Ron

Comment: In VBA:   `Left(myString, InStr(1, myString, "/company", vbTextCompare) - 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im sorry for posting the above, all it need was a **-1** at the end. I tried this before posting and it kept giving me and error messages. I have just tried it AGAIN and it has worked. I only posted as I was stuck on this for hours and could not find a solution.

[image]